# Failed to execute script python pyinstaller error

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I made my personal AI using Python. It has a lot of dependencies like logo, birthday, password, etc. Now I want to convert it into an app. I made it in Python Tkinter. When I try to convert it into an executable it says *failed to execute script*.

I used the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w jarvis.exe
```

This is the Python code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pyperclip
from passwordgenerator import pwgenerator
import os
import speech_recognition as sr
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import webbrowser
import datetime
import time
import pandas as p
import pyautogui
import PyDictionary

def password_genrator():
try:
    speak("What should I name the app?")
    t2.insert(END,"What should I name the app?")
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            password_name = format(text)

        except:
            speak("Sorry I can't recognize it")
            t2.insert("Sorry I can't recognize it")
    content = password_name
    password = pwgenerator.generate()
    Myfile = open('Main.txt', 'a')
    Myfile.write(f"{content} -- {password} \n")
    Myfile.close()
    t2.delete(1.0,END)
    speak("password is genrated press ctrl +v to paste")
    t2.insert("password is genrated press ctrl+V to paste")
    pyperclip.copy(password)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    speak("password wasn't genrated")
def wishthemininsta():
   webbrowser.open('www.instagram.com/' + item['insta id'])
   time.sleep(8)
   pyautogui.moveTo(760, 170)
   pyautogui.click()
   time.sleep(3)
   pyautogui.write(item['wish'])
   pyautogui.press('enter')
def speak(str):
    speak = Dispatch(("sapi.SpVoice"))
    speak.Speak(str)
def say():
t1.delete(1.0,END)
t2.delete(1.0,END)
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    except:
        t2.insert(END,"Sorry could not recognize what you said")

questions = {"hello\n": "hi","who are you\n": "I am Jarvis",
            "what can you do\n": "I can do many things like opening website etc :-)"
    , "will you marry me\n": "nhaa i need robot", "who is your creator\n": "my creator is tanush",
            "what is your version\n": "it is 3.0 with gui", "do you know something else\n": "i don't know",
            "hi\n": "hello"}

if t1.get(1.0,END) in questions:
    t2.insert(END,questions[t1.get(1.0,END)]+":\n")
    speak(questions[t1.get(1.0,END)]+":\n")
    print(questions[t1.get(1.0,END)]+":\n")
elif "generate password" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    password_genrator()
elif "open password" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    os.startfile("Main.txt")
elif "open Google" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    speak("opening Google")
    t2.insert(END, "opening Google")
    webbrowser.open('www.Google.com')

elif "open Instagram" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    speak("opening Instagram")
    t2.insert(END, "opening instagram")
    webbrowser.open('www.Instagram.com')

elif "open YouTube" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    speak("opening Youtube")
    t2.insert(END, "opening youtube")
    webbrowser.open('www.youtube.com')

elif "open SST class" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    speak("opening Sst class")
    t2.insert(END, "opening SST class")
    webbrowser.open('https://classroom.google.com/u/1/c/OTAwMDY1NzAwNDRa')

elif "open science class" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    speak("opening science class")
    t2.insert(END, "opening science class")
    webbrowser.open('https://classroom.google.com/u/1/c/OTAwMTM4OTQ3NDBa')

elif "open Maths class" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    speak("opening Maths class")
    t2.insert(END, "opening maths class")
    webbrowser.open('https://classroom.google.com/u/1/c/MTE2MTkyMDcyOTcz')

elif "open English class" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    speak("opening English class")
    t2.insert(END, "opening English class")
    webbrowser.open('https://classroom.google.com/u/1/c/OTQ2MTAyMDgyMzla')

elif "open Hindi class" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    speak("opening Hindi class")
    t2.insert(END, "opening hindi class")
    webbrowser.open('https://classroom.google.com/u/1/c/OTA3NzA5NzUxMTJa')

elif "open French class" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    speak("opening French class")
    t2.insert(END, "opening french class")
    webbrowser.open('https://classroom.google.com/u/1/c/ODA4OTE5MzE1MTFa')

elif "open Coumputer class" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    speak("opening Coumputer class")
    t2.insert(END, "opening coumputer class")
    webbrowser.open('https://classroom.google.com/u/1/c/OTMyNTY5MjM0Njla')

elif "open school mail" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    speak("opening gmail")
    t2.insert(END, "opening gmail")
    webbrowser.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?pli=1')

elif "check for birthday" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    speak("Checking for birthdays sir")
    t2.insert(END, "Checking for birthday")
    br = p.read_excel("Birthday.xlsx")
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m')
    # print(today)
    global item
    for index, item in br.iterrows():
        # print(index, item['date'])
        birthday_date = item['date'].strftime('%d-%m')
        name = item['name']
        print(item['name'])
    if str(birthday_date) in today:
        t2.delete(1.0,END)
        print(item['name'])
        speak("Today is the birthday of" + item['name'] + 'wishing her in 5 seconds')
        t2.insert(END, "Today is the birthday of" + item['name'] + "wishing her in 5 seconds")
        time.sleep(5)
        wishthemininsta()
    else:
        speak("no one's birthday is today Thank You")
        t2.insert(END, " no ones birthday today")
        print(today)
        print(birthday_date)
        print(type(birthday_date))
        print(type(today))
elif "antonym" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        speak("please say the antoym sir")
        t2.insert(END,"Pls say the antoynm sir")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            antonym_word = format(text)

        except:
            speak("Sorry I can't recognize it")
            t2.insert(END, "Sorry i can't recognize it")

    antonym = PyDictionary.PyDictionary.antonym(antonym_word)

    speak(f"the synonym of the word is {antonym}")

elif "the meaning" in t1.get(1.0,END):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        speak("please say the word sir")
        t2.insert(END, "please say the words sir")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            theword = format(text)
            word = PyDictionary.PyDictionary.meaning(theword)
            speak("The meaning of the word is" + str(word))
            t2.insert(END, "The meaning of the word is " + str(word))

        except:
            speak("Sorry I can't recognize it")
            t2.insert(END, "sorry i can't recognize it ")
else:
    speak("sorry I can't do that")
    t2.insert(END, 'Sorry i cant do that')

root = Tk()
img = Image("photo", file="voice.png")
root.tk.call('wm','iconphoto',root._w, img)
root.maxsize(width=400,height=400)
root.title("jarvis")
l1 = Label(root,text="You said:",font=("Bold",20)).place(x=0,y=0)
t1 = Text(root)
t1.place(x=1,y=40,height=100,width=400)
global t1value
t1value = t1.get(1.0,END)
b1 = Button(root,text="speak",command=say).place(x=1,y=150)
l2 = Label(root,text="Answer:",font=("Bold",20)).place(x=1,y=180)
t2 = Text(root)
t2.place(x=1,y=220,height=100,width=400)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Build the exe without `-w` option and run the exe in a terminal and see what errors are shown.  BTW, the command line `pyinstaller --onefile -w jarvis.exe` should be `pyinstaller --onefile -w jarvis.py` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the pyinstaller command incorrect, it should look more like below.

`pyinstaller --onefile jarvis.py`

for more information please refer to https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

or [How to convert .py to .exe file using pyinstaller](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/convert-py-to-exe-file-bc8721e318b8)